# pinentry-mac completely disables prompt for GPG passphrase

Tags: mac, gnupg

This is weird. I am using `pass` and `pinentry-mac` to unlock my passwords. My `gpg-agent.conf` uses `pinentry-mac` as its `pinentry-program`.

I'm not sure if I updated some dependency recently but suddenly decrypting passwords is now possible **without asking for passphrase** which I find as a serious problem. This is not a problem with `pass` as if I try using `gpg` directly to decrypt my encrypted files directly in terminal session, it's the same.

If I disable `pinentry-mac` then it starts working and I'm asked to put my passphrase every time. Any idea what can be the cause? I have tried restarting / killing `gpg-agent` and logging out of my user account (even restarting the machine) but result is the same.

Comment: Having exactly the same problem, no idea what's happening, for now switched to terminal-based `pinentry`.

Answer (score 11):

I have asked on GPG mailing list what's up and I've got interesting response:

> pinentry-mac has recently been upgraded to a different version which is
> based on pinentry upstream but with some specific macOS patches. This
> behavior you are seeing might be related to the "Save in keychain" option
> being set to "on" by default.

> Try opening macOS Keychain Access, search for "GnuPG" and delete
> the entry if you find one (create a backup if necessary first).

> After that, run the following commands in Terminal:

```
$ defaults write org.gpgtools.pinentry-mac UseKeychain -bool NO
$ killall pinentry-mac gpg-agent
```

> Now try signing / decrypting something and you should be asked
> for your passphrase.

Basically I updated `pinentry-mac` via `homebrew` and did not realize this was a new default behaviour and did not notice that the checkbox for saving passphrase into system keychain was turned on by default.

I have raised the issue on mailing list as I consider this dangerous default. This is response:

> I’ve filed an issue with the folks at homebrew.
> In their case I also don’t think it is a good choice especially since the default
> behavior was different before the update.

So maybe  they will fix it, maybe not.

Comment: Well I have had the exact same issue. Followed the answer of @user3056783: it worked (many thanks!)!. But then when I use pass again: I get prompt: have to enter the password and again I don't get the prompt to ask me for password for the next session: Ugely dangerous I think!